# Fetching Markdown file in Vue works only on dev server

Tags: vue.js

I'm fetching a markdown file that is located in a /src/blogs/.. directory in my Vue app.

Now it works on my localhost dev server when I run npm run dev. On my server however I get a 200 response but what I get back is a blank page and if I log the response, some HTML (see below). Why is the page loading fine on my dev server but I'm getting a blank page on my web server? I'm just using Render to deploy and haven't added any additional settings or rewrite rules.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-7469bb2a.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index-fbb83d74.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the component in question.

```
<script setup>
import { marked } from 'marked';
import { defineProps, ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const content = ref('');

const props = defineProps({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/src/blogs/${props.title}.md`);
    
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch Markdown content for ${props.title}`);
    }

    const markdown = await response.text();
    console.log(markdown)
    content.value = marked(markdown);
    console.log(content.value)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div v-html="content"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: /src/ shouldn't be served by a server, it's supposed to be bundled with the app. It's unclear why it works in dev but this shouldn't be so. Either use dynamic import instead of fetch, or move assets that aren't bundled with the app to public folder.